# Django pass variable context to custom filter

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to know the HTML to pass the CONTENT of a variable into a DJANGO CUSTOM TAG

the code, for example, would be something like this:

```
{% for id,name in data %}
  {% customTag id name %}
{% endfor %}
```

I need this to pass the ACTUAL CONTENTS of id, and not just "id" (the literal string)

and the answer is NOT found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag like all the previous posts say

Answer (score 0):

Well somebody posted this and then removed it... but it answered my question. The answer was to use the `takes_context` parameter.

I used a simple tag with this flag like in the example here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def current_time(context, format_string):
  timezone = context['timezone']
  return your_get_current_time_method(timezone, format_string)
```